# Using Meteoric to deploy Meteor.js, MongoError: auth fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteorite

When using Meteoric to start the meteor app that connects to a mongodb server that has auth enabled, first the variable is set:

```
export MONGO_URL = mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/myAppDb
```

Meteoric is configured as shown:

```
PRE_METEOR_START="export ENVIRONMENT=prod MONGO_URL=mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/myAppDb;"
```

Then meteor is launched using the command `meteoric deploy` The error appears:

```
MongoError: auth fails
```

**Question:** Why is meteor unable to access mongodb using `meteoric deploy`, but when launching meteor using `mrt`, mongodb access works fine?

I do notice that the Meteoric script contains the following code, what does the `-z` flag do?

```
if [ -z "$MONGO_URL" ]; then
    MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/$APP_NAME
```

Comment: -z means "test if the following string has a length of zero", it is used to test for an empty string in bash scripting.
You should be aware that in development mode (ie using "meteor/mrt" commands), Meteor handles launching a MongoDB daemon of its own and connecting to it, but in production mode (after bundling the application to make it a regular Node.js app), this is not the case and you have to handle the Mongo stuff yourself, so you might be tricked into thinking that the Mongo part is OK but it may not, as you clearly have an authentication failure error: you're sure of your credentials ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `-z`. When I disable auth for mongodb, launch meteor using `mrt` and access the site at port 3000, it does seem to use the same mongodb database as when it's launched using `meteoric deploy`. The credentials are correct, I can connect to it remotely using Robomongo when authentication is required on mongodb.

Comment: Could you try adding `authSource` to your query string eg. `mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/myAppDb?authSource=admin`

Comment: might want to look into this new project instead of using meteoric or keep an eye on it moving forward https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up